# Variable that can contain most memory space?

Tags: java, c

What type of variable that can contain 1,000,000,000(a decimal number) takes the most memory space?

1. int in C
2. string in C
3. string in Java(which uses unicode)

Comment: Strange question? The most wasteful representation would be a unicode string, assuming string in C used char[]

Comment: strings in C can be unicode, too...

Comment: Can we add an option 4: libgmp number? Surely no arbitrary-precision lib could be more bloated than gmp... :-)

Comment: @R - I'm sure I could invent one.  Unary anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Java String.  Under the hood A Java String consists of an object with 3 fields, one of which points to a separate array object containing the characters.  Plus of course, Java Strings are composed of 16 bit characters<sup>1</sup>.

If you are worried about memory usage over all other criteria, don't use Java.  But for most applications, memory usage is the least of your concerns.

It is worth noting that 1,000,000,000 can be represented using a Java `int` which will be the same size as a C signed or unsigned (32 bit) integer.

Furthermore, a C `int` is *not necessarily* big enough to represent 1,000,000,000.  On some platforms, `int` is 16 bits, and this is allowed by the C standard.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, this is Java platform dependent.  For example, in Java 9 they modified the `String` implementation to use one `byte` per character for strings that are composed entirely of characters in the range 0 to 255.  See [this article](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/java-9-compact-strings/).  But despite this, a Java string still takes more space than a C string.</sup>

Comment: Y - to clarify, C defines int as the native machine word size (so int can be 16, 32 or 64 bit etc). I guess technically a C int could be the most inefficient storage for 1BN in a 512bit machine word scenario, but hopefully I won't be around to see this.

Comment: @nonnb - to be absolutely technically correct, the C standard says that the range of `int` is at least -32758 to +32767.  It can be (and often is) greater than that.  However, the standard says *absolutely nothing* about `int` being the same size as a "native machine word".

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't really want to answer this directly, so you can have looks over here:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Also it might be useful how to convert between binary and decimal:

- http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal
- http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't state many storage requirements. As it is, you could have:

- 256-bit C `int`s that take 32 bytes to store anything (see @nonnb's comment)
- A wide C string (`wchar_t[]`) that uses UCS-4/UTF-32 characters (as all GNU implementations do, apparently)
- A C implementation that uses 32-bit `char`s (which would have to be on a system with 32-bit bytes)

Comment: Incidentally, 21-bit-or-larger `wchar_t` is the only way a conformant C implementation can support all of Unicode. It's also the recommended way (see the __STDC_ISO_10646__ macro in C99). Implementations with 16-bit `wchar_t` are simply broken.

Comment: what about multi-character sequences? what about UTF-8 & 16?